# Django: How to handle the real-time data that are being uploaded from Android device?

Tags: android, django

Assume we have a lot of android devices that trying to submit real-time data(a time stamp and some numbers) to an django application.

What we need to do is get the mean value of those data that being submitted per second and constantly update an android device.

How can I achieve these goal?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to memcache the data then store it in the datastore. Your mention of "mean value of all these data per second" doesn't make much sense to me; unless you have a lot of users or are generating a battery-draining amount of data, the mean value per second will probably just be whatever data happened to be submitted that second. Also, "realtime" may have deceived you; it *will* take time for data to be transmitted to the server and back down to the phone. Especially on EDGE and slower data networks, it could cause a lag of a few seconds.

It may be practical to do per-minute mean calculations; to that end, I would simply do a memcache tuple of the number of values received that minute and the mean they represent. Then when you get a new value, recalculate the mean (multiply the mean by the number of values [not including the increment] and add the new value, then divide by the new number of values). Store this in memcache, and move on. It's unlikely your data will get evicted within that minute if you're using memcache wisely, and if it is evicted, you lost at most a minute of data. If that's unacceptable, back it up to the datastore.